# How rapidly do human mitochondrial ribosomes turn over?

Tags: mitochondria, ribosome

How rapidly do human mitochondrial ribosomes turn over? 
The inside of the mitochondrion is a highly oxidizing environment that can damage RNA and DNA. How long do mitochondrial ribosomes last before needing to be replaced?